# Windows update seem to have screwed up my speakers

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, drivers, windows-update

Today I had a update notification. I didnt read it full and click OK. But since then my speaker and headphones are refusing to play. I checked Windows update history, and the update installed today is titled "2021-09 Cumulative Update for Windows 10 Version 21H1 for x64-based Systems (KB5005565)" with this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/september-14-2021-kb5005565-os-builds-19041-1237-19042-1237-and-19043-1237-292cf8ed-f97b-4cd8-9883-32b71e3e6b44).

Since, then I have tried fiddling with drivers, but no help. When I right click on the device and click Test, it says "Failed to Play test tone":

[image]

I uninstalled and reinstalled devices several times. Every time, this is what the device manager says "This device is working properly":

[image]

[image]

[image]

This is what troubleshooter says:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I manually restarted both these audio services:

[image]

I manually downloaded and installed [this](https://support.lenovo.com/bd/en/downloads/ds542123-audio-driver-for-windows-10-64-bit-s145-14iil-s145-15iil) audio driver which was suggested when I entered my laptop serial ID on Lenovo site. (I have S145-15IIL Laptop (ideapad) - Type 81W8).

Intel Driver Support Assistant did not suggest any audio driver:

[image]

Also when I tried to run IntelAudioService.exe by typing in start menu, it gave me following:
[image]

Not to mention I am unable to listen anything from headphones too.

I am not able to guess what went wrong? Is system restore / clean Windows install only option left? Will system restore screw anything? Cant I just reinstall everything related audio? without doing system restore or clean Windows install?

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall KB5005565?

Comment: Nope... will it work now? Especially given I have reinstalled drivers multiple times? Also how do I do it?

Comment: Btw I just found there is something called as "Servicing stack" which was also installed today. So I am proceeding with uninstalling both.

Comment: It’s impossible to uninstall Service Stack Updates nor should you ever attempt to do that. In the Windows Update History is there an entry your audio driver? That would indicate Windows Update installed the driver, of course the last update was released a week ago, no updates have been released in the last 48 hours.

Comment: Ohkay I havent done it yet. So wont do it yet. Currently uninstalling KB5005565. But just realized uninstall wizard named it "security update". Dont know how it may screw speakers...

Comment: There was no driver update on 23rd when Windows update happened. Though there were many on 24th as I myself was fiddling with them.

Comment: Update uninstalled. Still no help.

Comment: It’s not clear which Realtek audio device you have. If uninstalling the update, after a system reboot, didn’t help then it wasn’t the update that caused this behavior.  That doesn’t mean Windows Update didn’t install an incompatible device driver.

Comment: How do I know exatly which realtek audio device I have? I am talking about laptop's inbuilt speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I have this exact same issue and the only way I've been able to remotely solve it is via uninstalling the update.